# Changing most of the headers for a stored file do not have effect

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to change file's `Content-Disposition` header using both admin site UI and gsutil, but it doesn't work. I mean, by opening metadata URL I get a JSON with all altered values displayed correctly:

```
"contentDisposition": "attachment;filename=\"qwe\"",
"cacheControl": "public, max-age=3600",
"metadata": {
  "foo": " ã"
},
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect on the actual headers.

```
content-disposition: attachment
cache-control: public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

However, changing `Content-Type` works. I don't get it. It's like they're defaulting to something no matter what.